# Why does this cast to a trait object seem to change the borrow semantics?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker

**Edit:** In an earlier version of this I made a reference to GAT, which could divert attention from the intent of the question. I've edited the code to remove one of the associated types and simplify it overall. What I'd like to understand from this question:

**Why does `rustc` accept the boxed object as a concrete type but complain when the same object is cast to a boxed trait? What change can I make so that the boxed trait version is accepted?**

The trait I'm attempting to define is roughly:

> A thing that can create an iterator of some kind that borrows the thing and iterates values that have a lifetime greater than the thing but not necessarily as great as `'static`.

After some contriving I was eventually able to code that up (see `CreatesIterator`) along with a simple reference implementation struct (see `IteratorWithRef`). This concrete implementation works - it creates an iterator of the style specified which can iterate. If I cast this implementation to a trait object, the borrow checker shuts me down:

```
error[E0597]: `*creates_iterator_dyn` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
17 |         let _ = creates_iterator_dyn.iterate().count();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 |     }
   |     -
   |     |
   |     `*creates_iterator_dyn` dropped here while still borrowed
   |     borrow might be used here, when `creates_iterator_dyn` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::boxed::Box<dyn CreatesIterator<'_, '_, IteratorWithRef<'_, '_>>>`
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fa07f104331bf154480431cdd61c7459)

And code also below.

```rust
type LongTraitObjType<'collection, 'data> =
    Box<dyn CreatesIterator<'collection, 'data, IteratorWithRef<'collection, 'data>> + 'data>;

fn main() {
    let data = 1;

    // Works: concrete implementation:
    {
        let creates_iterator_impl = Box::new(CreatesIteratorImpl(vec![Wrapper(&data)]));
        let _ = creates_iterator_impl.iterate().count();
    }

    // Doesn't work: same as above, but cast to a trait object.
    {
        let creates_iterator_dyn: LongTraitObjType =
            Box::new(CreatesIteratorImpl(vec![Wrapper(&data)]));
        let _ = creates_iterator_dyn.iterate().count();
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Wrapper<'data>(&'data u32);

struct IteratorWithRef<'collection, 'data: 'collection> {
    reference: &'collection CreatesIteratorImpl<'data>,
    i: usize,
}
impl<'collection, 'data: 'collection> Iterator for IteratorWithRef<'collection, 'data> {
    type Item = Wrapper<'data>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.i < self.reference.0.len() {
            let ret = Some(self.reference.0[self.i].clone());
            self.i += 1;
            ret
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

trait CreatesIterator<'collection, 'data, E>
where
    'data: 'collection,
    E: Iterator + 'collection,
    <E as Iterator>::Item: 'data,
{
    fn iterate(&'collection self) -> E;
}

struct CreatesIteratorImpl<'data>(Vec<Wrapper<'data>>);

impl<'collection, 'data: 'collection>
    CreatesIterator<'collection, 'data, IteratorWithRef<'collection, 'data>>
    for CreatesIteratorImpl<'data>
{
    fn iterate(&'collection self) -> IteratorWithRef<'collection, 'data> {
        IteratorWithRef {
            reference: self,
            i: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *but surely there's a way to do this before then* — if there was in general, why do you think that GATs would be needed?

Comment: *have a lifetime greater than the thing* — how do you envision such code would even be possible? If the reference outlives the value it's referencing, then it would be pointing an invalid data, allowing memory unsafety.

Comment: @Shepmaster: _If there was in general, why do you think that GATs would be needed?_ — Well. If there's no way to do it, then there's no way to do it. But I don't know that there's no way to do it, hence the question. I just found the [galemu](https://crates.io/crates/galemu) crate for example, though I'm not yet sure that would work for me.

Comment: @Shepmaster: _how do you envision such code would even be possible?_ — An iterator of `usize`, which are `'static`, doesn't itself need to be `'static`. (Maybe this is just a misread of my description of the trait, which I can agree is not very clear.)

Comment: *`usize`, which are `'static`* — pedantically, `usize` don't contain references so they are neither `'static` or not. They *do* meet the trait bound of `'static` since any references (i.e. none) have a lifetime of that or longer.

Comment: You're right, and that's a meaningful distinction. Thanks.